# xfs: attempt to access beyond end of device

Tags: linux, xfs

on a redhat 7.2 (I have no root access there) commands like `ls`, `cat`, run in/on some directories/files created within an `xfs` filesystem hangs. I also observe on `dmesg` output continous errors like:

`[Thu Apr 12 10:22:27 2018] dm-3: rw=33, want=63076776, limit=62914560
[Thu Apr 12 10:22:27 2018] attempt to access beyond end of device
[Thu Apr 12 10:22:27 2018] dm-3: rw=33, want=63076784, limit=62914560
[Thu Apr 12 10:22:27 2018] attempt to access beyond end of device`

the filesystem size should be 50GB and it is 50GB on `df -h` output.

```
$ df -h /opt/data
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/datavg-optdata   50G  3.5G   47G   7% /opt/data
```

but when I check `lsblk` (only this works without root access for me) it shows 30GB `LV` device size. How it can be that FS was resized to 50GB on smaller 30GB LV? Or this is some other `xfs`  problem here?

```
sdb                      8:16   0   50G  0 disk
└─datavg-optdata    253:3    0   30G  0 lvm  /opt/data
```

Does somebody have any clue?

Comment: check your /etc/lvm history ... someone messed with it

Comment: Yep, looks like you shrank your volume and trashed your FS.

Comment: it was rather increased from 20G to 50G I have been told

Answer (score 0):

As frostschutz and psusi already commented, the most probable chain of events is that both the filesystem and the LV it's contained in were originally 50G in size.

The `xfs_growfs` command normally grows the filesystem to match the size of the underlying storage device (whether it's a LV, partition or a whole disk). The messages available within the `xfs_growfs` binary seem to indicate that even if you specify the new size of the filesystem yourself, it will sanity-check the answer, so growing the filesystem beyond the limits of the underlying LV should be impossible.

It is much more likely that someone has forgotten that the `lvreduce` command (without the `-r`option, if implemented) only reduces the LV, not the filesystem inside it... and that XFS fileystem does not have the capability for shrinking, only for expanding.

With LVM, extending an existing filesystem and LV is easy... so one might think that reducing them is just as easy. Unfortunately that isn't quite true: reducing a filesystem is often quite a bit more tricky than extending it.

Now, if the `datavg-optdata` LV was reduced from 50G to 30G, that means a 20G chunk at the tail end of the filesystem was cut off. If the reduced space was immediately put to some other use, the data that was in there is now lost.